# Pandas dates and events

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, time-series

I have a dataset of datetime and specific events that occured at these times. The dataset looks like this:
[image]

Now what I want is to have a new dataset having 2 columns. The first one is the dates with weeks frequency and the second one is how many events happened during this week from the above picture, so for example will be like this:

```
Dates            Events
27-12-2015       5
3 - 1-2016       6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) or [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html):

```
df['date_raised'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_raised'])

df.resample('W', on='date_raised').size().reset_index(name='Events')
```

Or:

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='W', key='date_raised')).size().reset_index(name='Events')
```

Comment: What if I want to make the same but for one class only? Like only technology how many of it occurred in each day?

Comment: @Omar - Then use `df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='W', key='date_raised'), 'primary_industry']).size().reset_index(name='Events')`